# R use stats::optimize in Rcpp, simple example fails to compile

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to use the R stats::optimize function in Rcpp because I haven't been able to find an Rcpp equivalent. The code below is my attempt at a simple example based on the Example in the optimize help, but fails.
Here's the R function and results

```
f <- function (x) (x - .33)^2
xmin <- optimize(f, c(0, 1), tol = 0.0001)
xmin
```

This returns

```
$minimum
[1] 0.333

$objective
[1] 0
```

Here's the Rcpp code that fails when sourcing it.

```
    #include <Rcpp.h>
    const double tolerance = 1e-0;

   // [[Rcpp::export]]
    Rcpp::NumericVector f(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
      return pow(x-0.33, 2);
    }
    
    Rcpp::List fTg_opt(const double optmin, const double optmax) {
      Rcpp::Environment base("package:stats");
      Rcpp::Function optimize_r = base["optimize"];    
      Rcpp::NumericVector interval = {optmin,optmax};
      return optimize_r(f, interval, tolerance);
    }
```

The Rstudio console has the following error messages.

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("R/cpp/testopt.cpp")
In file included from testopt.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:157:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/traits/traits.h:45:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/traits/is_convertible.h:35:10: error: function cannot return function type 'Rcpp::Vector<14> (Rcpp::Vector<14>)'
                static T MakeT() ;
                       ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h:770:75: note: in instantiation of template class 'Rcpp::traits::is_convertible<Rcpp::Vector<14> (Rcpp::Vector<14>), SEXPREC *>' requested here
            return wrap_dispatch_unknown(object, typename ::Rcpp::traits::is_convertible<T,SEXP>::type());
                                                                          ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h:787:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Rcpp::internal::wrap_dispatch_eigen<Rcpp::Vector<14> (Rcpp::Vector<14>)>' requested here
            return wrap_dispatch_eigen(object, typename traits::is_eigen_base<T>::type());
                   ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h:807:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Rcpp::internal::wrap_dispatch_unknown_importable<Rcpp::Vector<14> (Rcpp::Vector<14>)>' requested here
            return wrap_dispatch_unknown_importable(object, typename ::Rcpp::traits::is_importer<T>::type());
                   ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap_end.h:30:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Rcpp::internal::wrap_dispatch<Rcpp::Vector<14> (Rcpp::Vector<14>)>' requested here
          return internal::wrap_dispatch( object, typename ::Rcpp::traits::wrap_type_traits<T>::wrap_category() ) ;
                           ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/grow.h:44:26: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Rcpp::wrap<Rcpp::Vector<14> (Rcpp::Vector<14>)>' requested here
            return grow( wrap(head), tail ) ;
                         ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/grow.h:65:26: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Rcpp::internal::grow__dispatch<Rcpp::Vector<14> (Rcpp::Vector<14>)>' requested here
        return internal::grow__dispatch(typename traits::is_named<T>::type(), head, y);
                         ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/generated/grow__pairlist.h:45:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Rcpp::grow<Rcpp::Vector<14> (Rcpp::Vector<14>)>' requested here
        return grow( t1, grow( t2, grow( t3, R_NilValue ) ) ) ;
               ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/generated/Function__operator.h:45:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Rcpp::pairlist<Rcpp::Vector<14> (Rcpp::Vector<14>), Rcpp::Vector<14>, double>' requested here
            return invoke(pairlist(t1, t2, t3), R_GlobalEnv);
                          ^
testopt.cpp:13:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Rcpp::Function_Impl<PreserveStorage>::operator()<Rcpp::Vector<14> (Rcpp::Vector<14>), Rcpp::Vector<14>, double>' requested here
  return optimize_r(f, interval, tolerance);
                   ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [testopt.o] Error 1
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++14 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Users/gcn/Documents/workspace/ISIMIPData/R/cpp" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c testopt.cpp -o testopt.o
Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("R/cpp/testopt.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Comment: Please look into nloptr (with [RcppNLOptExample](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppnloptexample)) or into RcppEnsmallen. Maybe also at my RcppDE package to see how I pass compiled functions around. In short, it is more work than you do above which is why the above blows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems here is that you assume that becomes a function you submit to compilation under `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` is callable under its exported name.

It is not. Try `Rcpp::sourceCpp(..., verbose=TRUE)`, i.e. add that arguments, to see what is *really* called.  Those you could pass around (using SEXP argunments and results, but they are unwieldy).

To prove, here is a 'working but useless' version of your code. If we pass `f()` from R too, everything is callable.

Morale:  The interface still is `SEXP .Call("name", SEXP a, SEXP b, ...)` even if Rcpp hides that.  No Free Lunch (TM).  But as my comment hinted, there are optimization packages you can use with Rcpp.

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List fTg_opt(Rcpp::Function f, const double optmin, const double optmax) {
    Rcpp::Environment base("package:stats");
    Rcpp::Function optimize_r = base["optimize"];
    Rcpp::NumericVector interval = {optmin,optmax};
    Rcpp::List res = optimize_r(f, interval);
    return res;
}

/*** R
f <- function (x) (x - .33)^2
xmin <- optimize(f, c(0, 1), tol = 0.0001)
xmin

fTg_opt(f, 0, 1)
*/
```

#### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/68674076/question.cpp")

> f <- function (x) (x - .33)^2

> xmin <- optimize(f, c(0, 1), tol = 0.0001)

> xmin
$minimum
[1] 0.33

$objective
[1] 0


> fTg_opt(f, 0, 1)
$minimum
[1] 0.33

$objective
[1] 0
```

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand. The f I created and then attempted to use in the R optimize function is not the right 'kind'. I checked this by creating f from cpp and then used it in optimize in R. And it works!  I also took a quick look at RcppDE which looks like a more sophisticated version of the optimize function in stats. Some more questions are sure to come.

Comment: Yes. Going for a walk in the woods helps.  In essence the functions you "send to" `sourceCpp()` are meant for (eventual) use by R; for use by C++ it is different and you are further down the stack (SEXP out, SEXPs in).  Rcpp can help, but once again wishing alone does not make it so.  But hey it has been done before and you will get there too.  Remember what I said last week about baby steps instead of triple-saults?